# When retrieving values from a hash table with linear probing, how do we know if the wanted value had not been shifted?

Tags: hash-tables

So, after a collision, a piece of information gets stored in the *next* bucket. When retrieving the value later with a key, how do we know it has not been shifted due to a collision and that we are in fact receiving the wrong value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With linear probing, the appropriate bucket stores both the value and the literal key. So when retrieving, you start in the bucket determined by the hash code and check if the key is the same. If it's not, you move to the next one and check again, and repeat until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but do linked lists also have both a value and the literal key? Otherwise, what is the point?

Comment: @boreora For the most part linked lists don't have keys at all. If you're asking about the linked-list approach to dealing with collisions in a hash table, then yes.